# How to create Repeater fields using Advanced Custom Fields?

Tags: plugins, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields and trying to create a field with the [field type Repeater](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/field-types/repeater/).

But the problem is that the Repeater option doesn't appear in the select list with the field types. I can't figure out what's wrong.

I'm using Advanced custom fields v3.5.3 and Wordpress 3.4.2.

What could be the issue?

Comment: That's a [premium add-on](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/), you have to pay for it.

Answer (score 2):

The Repeater field is a [premium add-on](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/), and you have to buy a licence key:

[image]